# Unsure of bilinear form on Hilbert space in terms of quadratic form?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quadratic-forms

I am reading a book on Hilbert spaces and it mentions the following fact about quadratic forms and bilinear functionals:

If $\hat{\psi}$ is a the quadratic form induced by a bilinear functional $\psi$ on a complex vector space then we have that

$$\psi(x, y) = \hat{\psi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}(x + y)\bigg) - \hat{\psi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}(x - y)\bigg) + i\hat{\psi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}(x + iy)\bigg) - i\hat{\psi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}(x - iy)\bigg).$$

Where does this identity come from?

Comment: It is called a polarisation identity and follows by developing the expression. Where does it come from,... difficult to say, in books I haven't seen any references to a first appearence. There is a similar one for real bilinear forms  $B(x,y)=q(x+y)-q(x-y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called *Polarization Identity*. The $1/2$ should be $1/4$. Also, the formula applies to *sesquilinear* forms rather than bilinear. It is usually written as 
$$
\psi(x,y)=\frac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\,\hat\psi(x+i^k y).
$$

Not sure what you expect regarding where "it comes from". It is the identity that relates the inner product with the norm in a Hilbert space. From that point of view, it could be written as 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\,\|x+i^ky\|^2.
$$
It is likely that the first mathematicians who considered complex Hilbert spaces figured it out. It is not a far-fetched generalization of the identity in the real case, 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\frac14\,(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2).
$$